# Apollo gql queries hanging when having more than one tab open on the same page

Tags: reactjs, go, graphql, apollo

We picked up a rather poorly written legacy project that has two APIs: one for authentication and another called dashboard.

With a certain level of inconsistency, some of the dashboard api calls hang if I open two tabs on the same page. If I refresh one of the pages (or close it/navigate elsewhere), the other's query will instantly succeed.

This seems to happen somewhat randomly; just before posting this question, I noticed it was working fine on localhost and so I pushed my latest changes to staging, restarting the backends in the process. After the restart, the problem returned.

It only seems to happen when both tabs are using the same browser and both are incognito or not. I've observed it while using both Google Chrome and Opera, both locally and on stage.

The frontend is written in React, using `apollo/client` `v3.6.8`, `graphql` `v15.8.0`. Both backends are written in go, using `graphql-go/graphql` `v0.7.9` and `graphql-go/handler` `v0.2.3`.

Comment: Can you add some logging to see where the hang is happening? Can you replicate the problem locally?

Comment: Yes, I can replicate it locally. Sometimes it seems to not happen, though. I added some loggers to see if it hangs but it seems to not even enter the resolver

Comment: Can you show some relevant code for readers to look at?